# Laravel - variable and lang system

Tags: php, laravel, variables, routes, lang

I will show an example, I'm not good at writing English and it's better for the comprehension.

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home')->withSucces("@lang('home.account_create_confirm')");
});
```

Here is a route and here is  the code from the page:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-success">
        {{ $success }}
    </div>
</div>
```

The message "home.account_create_confirm" is "your account has been created", but when I go to the page, instead of this, the page display this:

```
@lang('home.account_create_confirm')
```

Screenshot to understand:
https://gyazo.com/623fd5899b95819b6196bbae0197b1d4

I am sorry for this, I know that I'm a beginner and it must be evident for must of you!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Just a guess: Have you tried removing the double quotes around `"@lang(...)"`?

Comment: yes but I found the solution, it was to replace @lang with trans('...')

Answer (score 3):

**@lang** is a tag of blade template processor and is not available in your controller. use **trans()** instead:

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('home')->withSucces(trans('home.account_create_confirm'));
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much for answering and for your help, I understand now why it wasn't working haha! Have a good day/night!